# How to find the css class count inside the div in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to find out the count of certain class name in my html

for example this is my html

```
<div class="main-element">

    <div class="child-element">
    </div>

    <div class="child-element">
    </div>

    <div class="child-element">
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to find out the class name count of child-element

The output should be 3

How I can find out the count in jquery?

this is my jQuery code

```
var i=0;
$(".main-element").each(function() {
   var element = $(this);
   if (element.hasClass("child-element")) {
    alert(i++);
   }
});
```

Comment: sorry i have just edited the code please check it out

Comment: `$(".main-element > .child-element").length` or if you must `$(".main-element").children().each(....`

Comment: wait letme try this

Comment: Combined with https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/